# unable to get the access token through [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] in iphone sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a facebook app. I have implemented the login using class FBSDKLoginManager. At first time when i login the facebook, success block return the **FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult** object which contain the **access token object (FBSDKAccessToken object)** which is use full for share the contain .But at second time (after relaunching the app) when I try to get the access token using the function  **[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]** return nil. So how to get the **access token (FBSDKAccessToken object)** second time without login facebook again.

Comment: It should keep track of the access token after restarts, so this is unexpected behaviour. Are you sure you are correctly logged the first time?

Comment: Did you get the solution for saving FBSDKAccessToken for second time? I am also facing this issue

Answer (score 22):

Try This code. Based on Facebook SDK version 4.0

**AppDalegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)btnFacebookPressed:(id)sender {
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             // Process error
         }
         else if (result.isCancelled)
         {
             // Handle cancellations
         }
         else
         {
             if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
             {
                 NSLog(@"result is:%@",result);
                 [self fetchUserInfo];
             }
         }
     }];
}

-(void)fetchUserInfo
{
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
    {
        NSLog(@"Token is available : %@",[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]tokenString]);

        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, link, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, birthday, bio ,location ,friends ,hometown , friendlists"}]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error)
             {
                 NSLog(@"resultis:%@",result);
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
             }
         }];

    }

}
```

`viewDidLoad` call this method you get access token after login

```
[self fetchUserInfo];
```

Comment: :: nice answer +1... but can't able to fetch friendlistslist,hometown, friends, location, birthday etc ... can you please help out this??

Comment: @BandishDave see www.developer.facebook.com because many change in SDK. If your friend use your app with Facebook login then you get those friend only.

Answer (score 19):

You need to call

```
[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions]
```

**Before**

```
[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This code. Based on Facebook SDK version 6.0 and above

```
- (IBAction)fbIntegration:(id)sender
{

    FBSDKLoginManager *loginmanager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

    [loginmanager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"public_profile"] fromViewController:Nil handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)

     {
         if (error)
         {
             // Process error
             NSLog(@"======error%@",error);
         }
         else if (result.isCancelled)
         {
             // Handle cancellations
             NSLog(@"canceled");
         }
         else
         {
             if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
             {
                 NSLog(@"result is:%@",result);
                 [self fetchUserInfo];
             }
         }
     }];

}
-(void)fetchUserInfo
{
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
    {
        NSLog(@"Token is available : %@",[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]tokenString]);

        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, link, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, birthday, bio ,location ,friends ,hometown , friendlists"}]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error)
             {
                 NSLog(@"%@",connection);
              }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
             }
         }];

    }

}
```

hope this will helps to others.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying the your application on simulator, please try on a real device because simulator has a user defaults bug.

`Falling back to loading access token from NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug`