# Facebook SDK iOS use user data

Tags: ios, facebook

How to get user name, user image, user email when login: didCompleteWithResult: err: method is called in Facebook SDK for iOS version 4.4.
I want to set these values to properties.

```
- (void)loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result error:(NSError *)error {
if (error) {

} else if (result.isCancelled) {

} else {
    //I want get user info here and set values to properties.
    self.userName =
    self.userImage =
    self.userEmail = 

 }
}
```

If you know other solutions, please tell me about it.

Comment: refer this link, help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/30275960/4536708

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"user_photos"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
       [self fetchData]

    } 
}];
```

and in fetchData method

```
- (void)fetchData {

[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

     if (!error) {

         DLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);

         self.userFirstName = [result objectForKey:@"first_name"];
         self.userLastName = [result objectForKey:@"last_name"];
         self.userEmail = [result objectForKey:@"email"];
         NSString *facebookId = [result objectForKey:@"id"];

         self.userProfileImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", facebookId];
         DLog(@"URL=%@",self.userProfileImage);

       }
   }];
 }
```