# Unable to access public_profile permission in IOS(Facebook SDK)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook login in my app. Actually public_profile is a default permission. For Facebook integration i have used a wrapper class. Problem is that i am getting only id and name from Facebook SDK while logging in.
Can anyone guess the problem??
[image: **Sample log from XCode**]

Comment: add your facebook code here

Comment: `permissions:@[@"user_about_me", @"email", @"user_birthday"] ` allow these permissions in your code.

Comment: you can use latest Facebook SDK 4.x then you get  user info (specifiers every field you get). refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/30275960/4536708

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify each field you want to retrieve if you're using v2.4 of the Graph API.

See my answer at

- [Facebook only returning name and id of user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692355/facebook-only-returning-name-and-id-of-user/31692908#31692908)

Comment: could you please post the code for objective c.. please