# Set delegate for custom Facebook login button

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I've custom button if created in storyboard and connected to my `ViewController` :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *FBConnectButton;
```

This button has an action:

```
- (IBAction)FBConnectAction:(id)sender {
//    
    NSLog(@"SDK: Facebook iOS SDK Login");

    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

    [login
     logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"]
     fromViewController:self
     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Process error");
         } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
         } else {
             NSLog(@"Logged in");
         }
     }];
```

}

There is too `delegate` for login to return the result :

```
-(void)loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result error:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"%@",result);




}

-(void)loginButtonDidLogOut:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton{



}
```

How do i say to my `UIButton` and set its delegate to `FBSDKLoginButton`, so after login it returns login data ?

Comment: Isn't that already taken care under that block, `logInWithReadPermissions `? Do you want to take that information from there to some other class?

Comment: Already here `handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Process error");
         } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
         } else {
             NSLog(@"Logged in");
         }
     }];`

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/30275960/4536708

Comment: @rptwsthi, i can't get access to the data, like public profile or email ... i tried `NSLog(@"Logged in%@",result.token);` or without token ! i can't get the user data !

Answer (score 0):

The `didCompleteWithResult` and `loginButtonDidLogOut` delegate methods are for the `FBSDKLoginButton` which is not the same as custom login. For custom login you already have the callback block `handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {...}` where you should expect the results.

Once you get back the results in the callback block, you can check if the user has granted the permissions that you have asked for. e.g. for `email`:

```
if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
    NSLog(@"Email permission granted.");
    [self makeGraphAPICall];
}
```

Once you know you have the permissions, make a Graph API call to get the required data, something like:

```
- (void)makeGraphAPICall {
    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:@"/me?fields=id,name,email"
                                  parameters:nil
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Required User Data: %@", result);
    }];
}
```

Also, if you require permissions that need review and approval, make sure you are testing this with an admin/developer of the app.