# iOS 9 not logged in Facebook login?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am using Xcode 7.0, testing on iOS 9.0.2 and using Facebook SDK 4.7.0. **Code=308 "(null)"** issue occur in iOS 9.I am using objective-c code in my project. how to resolve this?
Below attach my code.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

 [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"email", @"user_friends"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error){

    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) { startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

             if (!error) {
             }

         }];

    }
}];
```

Comment: Refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30275960/4536708

Comment: Thanks your response.Facebook login working iOS 8.particularly not working in iOS 9.

Comment: yes but only minor syntax changes all code working properly. @Anbu

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya Thanks. what syntax changes ?

Comment: In iOS9 added this line fromViewController. @Anbu

Comment: what the error u faced in iOS 9

Comment: I try to facebook login getting response Code=308 "(null)".@Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 4):

iOS9.2.1

This fixes my 308 issues

Open as 'source code', plist file, search for LSApplicationQueriesSchemes, then add/modify as needed.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
 FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
         if (error)
         {
             // Process error
         }
         else if (result.isCancelled)
         {
             // Handle cancellations
         }
         else
         {
             if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
             {
                 NSLog(@"result is:%@",result);
                 [self fetchUserInfo];
                 [login logOut];
             }
         }
     }];
```

Comment: Thank You so much.It's working now @Dharmesh.I have one doubt iOS 9 app facebook login not using facebook app.now showing one pop up.this pop not maintane access token so I have login multiple time any solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
 - (IBAction)facebookClick:(id)sender {
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
     [login logOut];
    login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error)
        {
                 NSLog(@"Process error");
             //   [login logOut];
         } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
            // [login logOut];
         } else {
             NSLog(@"Logged in");
             [self getUserInformation];
         }
     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to the new iOS 9 url handling scheme

You need to add the trusted urls to your `plist` under `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987986/ios-9-not-opening-instagram-app-with-url-scheme)

Comment: Hi @Tuss 
Please explain breifly?
I try to facebook login iOS9 device through error responce

Comment: Hi @Tuss
I try to facebook login iOS 9 device getting error responce Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.login Code=308 "(null)"
My Appdelegate code
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];

Comment: Info.plist code
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
 </array>
I don't know What I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

For **iOS 10** with **xCode 8**

Set **ON** your project's **Keychain Sharing** within **Capabilities** tab. **[image: target]**