# login with facebook in Xcode and iOS 9 with objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, authentication

I am trying to create an application and using `Login` with `Facebook` but it always show `error` **Auth2**, Please help me on this problem.

```
2016-05-03 15:14:36.213 loginFB[631:124818] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
2016-05-03 15:14:36.225 loginFB[631:124818] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
2016-05-03 15:14:36.863 loginFB[631:124818] Warning: Attempt to present <FBSDKContainerViewController: 0x12659bf90> on <ViewController: 0x12655a140> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Comment: fb page is open or not?

Comment: You're missing new condition in iOS9: `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`

Comment: yes it's open but its give error every time

Comment: @Larme where i use this????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 9 not loged in Facebook login?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367944/ios-9-not-loged-in-facebook-login)

Comment: i have use this **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** in my plist

Comment: @Larme but its always error and not generate token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

last night struggle this problem i got correct Answer for my problem

```
    - (IBAction)loginFBAction:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button=sender;
    if ([button isSelected]) {
        //        [fb facebookLogOut];
        [button setSelected:NO];
    }else{
        FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        [login
         logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile",@"user_friends",@"email",@"user_birthday"]
         fromViewController:self
         handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
             if (error) {
                 NSLog(@"Process error");

             } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                 NSLog(@"Cancelled");

             } else {
                 NSLog(@"Logged in");
                 [self checkUser];
             }
         }];        [button setSelected:YES];
    }
}
- (void)checkUser{
    NSMutableDictionary* parametersDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [parametersDic setValue:@"id, name, email, birthday, picture" forKey:@"fields"];

    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                  parameters:parametersDic
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
        // Handle the result
        NSLog(@"result %@",result);
        NSString* nameFB = [result objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString* emailFB = [result objectForKey:@"email"];
    }];
}
```

this is code but you need to make sure that you have enable the your app from FB developer page if you are not enable that your application will not work i am showing here the pic of that [image]

here you are seeing **green light** side of app name for **enable this green** you need to go **APP review** option and **public you app** like this [image]

**now you will be able to lunch your application and get access for the fb login**.

Comment: if you get any problem in this then you can directly contact me on my email **im.anupgupta03@gmail.com**

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this in your .plist file:

```
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
   <array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fbapi20130214</string>
    <string>fbapi20130410</string>
    <string>fbapi20130702</string>
    <string>fbapi20131010</string>
    <string>fbapi20131219</string>
    <string>fbapi20140410</string>
    <string>fbapi20140116</string>
    <string>fbapi20150313</string>
    <string>fbapi20150629</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
             <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```