# Why FBlogin button delegate method not calling?

Tags: ios, objective-c

*Steps I was done in my project:*

1. Fb appid i was created:
2. I have added this key in my `info.plist`.
3. sdk all imported to my project.
4. `appdelegate.m` file

   ```
   -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
               openURL:(NSURL *)url
     sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
            annotation:(id)annotation {

       NSString *stringURL = [ url absoluteString];
       if([stringURL containsString:@"fb"])
       {

           return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                 openURL:url
                                                       sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                              annotation:annotation];

       }
       else
       {

           return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
                         sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                annotation:annotation];

       }
   }
   ```
5. my button class is fbsdkloginbutton,delegate is successfully given to the **viewcontroller**.

6.[image]

7.Two button delegation method also implemented

```
-(BOOL)loginButtonWillLogin:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
{
    return YES;
}
-(void)loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result error:(NSError *)error

{
    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"==%@",error);
    }
    else
    {

        NSUserDefaults *pref=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [pref setObject:_txtcity.text forKey:@"CITY"];

        [self _loadData];

    }
}
-(void)loginButtonDidLogOut:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
{
    NSLog(@"user logged out");
    [[FBSDKLoginManager new] logOut];
}

- (void)_loadData {
//    FBSDKGraphRequest *request=[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{ @"fields" : @"id,name,picture.width(100).height(100),email"} tokenString:nil version:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    // For more complex open graph stories, use `FBSDKShareAPI`
    // with `FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent`
    /* make the API call */
    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:@"/me"
                                  parameters:@{ @"fields" : @"id,name,picture.width(100).height(100),emailid"}
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
//      @{ @"fields" : @"id,name,picture.width(100).height(100),email"}
    //@{ @"fields" : @"id,name,picture.width(100).height(100)"}]
    //    @{@"fields":@"email,public_profile"}
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
        if(result)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",connection);
            // Handle the result
            NSLog(@"%@",result);
            NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;
            NSLog(@"====%@",request);
            NSString *facebookID = userData[@"id"];
            name = userData[@"name"];
            //                    NSString *location = userData[@"location"][@"name"];

            email = userData[@"email"];
            imgurl = userData[@"picture"][@"data"][@"url"];
            NSLog(@"this is email=%@facebookid==%@name==%@picture url%@",email,facebookID,name,imgurl);
            NSData *Data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgurl]];
            UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:Data];
            datas.imgProfilePhoto=image;
            one=@"1";
            [self multiform];
        }


    }];


}
```

Comment: Refer this link may be you help http://stackoverflow.com/a/30275960/4536708

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya so you are telling to change the flow of my code?

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya its giving me Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.login Code=301 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.login error 301.)"

Comment: latest sdk bro 7.0 @DharmeshDhorajiya ,first its worked after some times its didn't work

Comment: yes bro i done @DharmeshDhorajiya

Comment: same code i just copy paste ,first time its worked for me ,after that its giving me the error message bro @DharmeshDhorajiya

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the button is given FBSDKLoginButton class in XIB.

Comment: y i need to give that fbsdkloginbutton instead of that i am using touchup inside method..

Comment: because when you load the xib, u have to tell the xcode that which class element you want it to load