# Trouble getting Facebook User Name

Tags: ios, facebook

Using FBSDK, I set up a sharing button as follows:

```
-(void) setFBShareButton{
    [self.facebookButton addTarget:self action:@selector(postFacebook:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    FBSDKShareLinkContent * content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc]init];
    //some logic
    self.FBSharebutton.shareContent = content;
}
```

When that button is tapped, this method is called:

```
-(void)postFacebook:(UIButton*)sender{
    [self.FBSharebutton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
       //nothing...
    }
}
```

At that point, I need to get the Facebook User Name, but as you can see in my comments above, I don't have an access token, that I think I need for that information.

For the record, I also have this in my AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                             didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

What part am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to get the access token through \[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken\] in iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30274693/unable-to-get-the-access-token-through-fbsdkaccesstoken-currentaccesstoken-in)

Comment: so your issue is actually not about getting a user name as it says so in the headline, but an access token?